# Vidyo - Participant count before you enter the video room

Tags: angular, vidyo

We are setting up a telemedicine solution where a doctor joins via the web and the patient via a mobile app or desktop web page. 
We would like to prevent a patient from entering the video room without the doctor being present. Is it possible to get a participant count via the API before allowing the patient to connect into the video room? 
We are using Angular on the client side. 
Your API reference mentions RoomStats > participantStats 
Could that be used before connecting?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we do not have API to check for the number of participant in a room without connecting to it first.
You can however implement application location whereby the invitation is only sent to the patient or the button to join is only enabled once the doctor connects and receive a onSuccess callback.